# Adding index to FME MapInfo FeatureWriter

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I need to add an index to a FeatureWriter transformer in FME so it can speed searches up.  I cannot find this option in the FeatureWriter settings.  I found doing this in a standard FME writer very easy.  But just need some help setting this field in the FeatureWriter.  If you have a look at the image, you can see what I mean.  When I run the workflow no indexes come through even though some are set in the initial data too.  I must be missing something because it can't be this difficult to set an index field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version? I see the index column in the FeatureWriter same as in the default MapInfo writer. Using FME Desktop 2016.1.0.1 (20160516 - Build 16494 - WIN32)

[image]

Comment: Thankyou.  I'll get the update, currently using FME 2016.0.1.0 (20160130 - B16174 - Win64) has to be the issue.

Comment: If possible I would try to install the current (2016.1.1) release.